token from Google Auth not matching otplib authenticator.verify function
I'm trying to get 2fa to work on a backend project.
I have a function that created and store the secret:
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { authenticator } from 'otplib';
import { ClientService } from 'src/client/client.service';

@Injectable()
export class TwoFactorAuthService {
constructor(private readonly prisma: ClientService)

public async generateTwoFactorAuthSecret(loggedUserEmail: string) {
 const user = await this.prisma.users.findFirst({
   where: { email: loggedUserEmail },
 });
 const secret = authenticator.generateSecret();

 const otpAuthUrl = authenticator.keyuri(user.email, 'MyApp', secret);

 await this.prisma.users.update({
  where: {id: user.id},
  data: {2faSecret: secret}
 });

 return {otpAuthUrl}
}
}

Then with that otpAuthUrl I have the qrcode to read using google authenticator, but the thing is when I use the code provided by the auth APP it doesn't match.
Here's the function to verify the code:
async verifyTwoFaCode(code: string, user: Users) {
 //code = 6 number token from google auth APP
 return authenticator.verify({
   token: code,
   secret: user.2faSecret,
 });
}

The 'authenticator.verify' function returns false.
There's a function that actually gives me the correct code:
const correctCode = authenticator.generate(user.2faSecret); //6 number code
 return authenticator.verify({
   token: correctCode,
   secret: user.2faSecret,
 });

If I do this it returns true, which tells me that the code provided by google auth APP is incorrect. How can I get this working properly??

Is this a true and accurate representation of your code?
